# Why does my program crash if it doesn't fit in the display?

Tags: 12.04, unity, 14.04, xfce

I used to make programs for my E-ink PocketBook using SDK from http://pbsdk.vlasovsoft.net/ on 32bit Ubuntu 12.04, and it worked great. Recently I went to 14.04 64bit.

I use `gcc` with the `-m32` option for compiling for emulator which what this question is about. I spent a whole day fighting with `ld` and getting the compiler to work. Finally, my programs seemed to compile, but when I ran them they just crashed with `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Later I found out that program crashes on any screen drawing function. The emulator makes a window with dimensions of 600x800 and my laptop display uses 1366x768. It was no problem on Ubuntu 12.04, but it seems to be an issue here. If I tell the emulator to rotate the the window 90 degrees, it doesn't crash. I attached another display with dimensions of 1600x1200, and it doesn't crash. What should I do?

Everything works good with Xfce.

If you comment `FullUpdate()` line it will not crash.

```
#include "inkview.h"

int main_handler(int type, int par1, int par2)
{
    ClearScreen(); //Doesn't draw to screen, only buffer
    FullUpdate(); //Draws to screen
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    InkViewMain(main_handler);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
** Message: Command 501 selected

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Maybe it has to do something with `overlay-scrollbar`?

Comment: When it crashes, what error message of you get? Also you will need to post your code. Finally this might be closed as off topic as it is more a question about coding and not necessarily about Ubuntu.